# Get all elements from associative array and send them via POST method in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, email, post, associative-array

I'm developing a simple contact form.
I have an associative array `$_POST['hid']`. Something like this:

> Array["0" => "Location0",  "1" => "Location1",  "2" => "Location2"]

I'm trying to send this array as an email with a view on client side as:

Locations:

- Location0;
- Location1;
- Location2.

I'm using this PHP code but it returns me only the last element from the array in the email...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['hid']); $i++) {
    $a=$_POST['hid'][$i];
}

$email_content .= "Locations:\n$a\n";
```

Also I tried to send `$_POST['hid']` but it returns me `Array` in the email.

So the question is how can I send all array values via POST method and receive them in the email. Not just first or last element.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a dot (.) before $a

```
$a = 'Locations:<ul>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['hid']); $i++) {
    $a .= '<li>' . $_POST['hid'][$i] . '</li>';
}
$a .= '</ul>';
$email_content = $a;
```

Comment: Hi Gyandeep. I used your solution. 
Just one thing is that I receive those HTML tags like:
`<ul><li>Location0</li><li>Location1</li><li>Location2</li></ul>`.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to make it like a ul list. But those HTML tags are visible on client side. I mean receiver will get the email with visible HTML tags ul and li...

Comment: do you use librairy or something to write your mail ?

Comment: because if you use it you are surely a method like "writeHTML"

Comment: Nope, just pure PHP. Any suggestions?

Comment: then it's probably that you missing the header like '"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"'

Comment: Oh. It's true. Thank you guys for fast help. These both solutions work perfect.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['hid']); $i++) {
     $a=$_POST['hid'][$i];
     $email_content .= "Locations:\n$a\n";
}
```

you change the variable $a all the time, that's why you have always the same value.

you can do it by a shorter way also like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['hid']); $i++) {
     $email_content .= "Locations:\n".$_POST['hid'][$i]."\n";
}
```

or more clean (to me) like:

```
foreach($_POST['hid'] as $location) {
     $email_content .= "Locations:\n$location\n";
}
```

EDIT:
but the result isn't the one expected so more like this:

```
$email_content .= "Locations:\n";
$locations = "";
foreach($_POST['hid'] as $location) {
    $locations .="$location\n";
}
$email_content .= $locations;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this instead:

```
$array = []
array_map(function($item) use (&$array){
 $array[] = $item;
},$_POST['hid']);
```

$array should contain all your values

Answer (score 0):

```
$hid = $_POST['hid'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($hid); $i++) {
   $a=$hid[$i];
   $email_content .= "Locations:\n$a\n";
}
```

Or you can use foreach, goes like this:

```
$hid = $_POST['hid'];
foreach ($hid as $h){
   $a=$h[$i];
   $email_content .= "Locations:\n$a\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this:

```
$a = 'Locations:<ul>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['hid']); $i++) {
    $a .= '<li>' . $_POST['hid'][$i] . '</li>';
}
$a .= '</ul>';
$email_content = $a;
```